# list Directory Contents

Tags: node.js, readdir

listDirectoryContents

- The function takes two parameters, a directory name as the first parameter and a callback function as the second parameter
- The function invokes the callback with an array of strings representing the contents of the directory
- Use the fs library in Node.js to read the directory asynchronously
- The function should return the result of invoking the callback function with the directory contents
- This is referred to as callback chaining

```
    listDirectoryContents(directoryName, callback) {
        fs.readdir(directoryName, function(err, dirent) {
            if
            (err) {
                return console.log(err);
            }

            for (var i=0; i<dirent.length; i++) {


             callback (dirent[i].toString());

            }


        });
    }
```

i got an error : TypeError: files.forEach is not a function

any helps please

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Is it possible the error is coming from your callback function? If so, what does that code look like?

Comment: does it show the files of the dir ? because I got the error : TypeError: files.forEach is not a function

Comment: listDirectoryContents('C:\\Test', function(result) { console.log(result); }); gave me the result "file2.txt, file3.txt, Folder 1"